# In RestAssured jsonPathEvaluator not giving correct values for double value

Tags: rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

I have a json response as shown below :-

```
{
  "someField": [
    {
      "abc": "abcdId"
    }
  ],
  "someId": "pqrsId",
  "oneTier": {
    "startThreshold": 25000,
    "endThreshold": 74999.99
  },
  "nextTier": {
    "startThreshold": 75000,
    "endThreshold": 149999.99
  }
}
```

When I try to print

```
response.getBody().asString()
```

I can get the see the value of nextTier.endThreshold as '14999.99'
but when I do

```
response.getBody().jsonPath().get("nextTier.maxThreshold").toString();
```

I am seeing the value as 14999.98'.

Not able to figure out why this is happening.

Comment: There is no `maxThreshold` in your json. Do you mean `endThreshold`?

Answer (score 0):

The default config `JsonPathConfig` defines `NumberReturnType = FLOAT_AND_DOUBLE`, this may lose the precision when converting between   types.

Fortunately, RestAssured has a solution for this kind of issue. You can config `NumberReturnType = BIG_DECIMAL` then it saves the precision of floating-point number.

```
JsonPath.config = new JsonPathConfig().numberReturnType(JsonPathConfig.NumberReturnType.BIG_DECIMAL);
BigDecimal endThreshold = JsonPath.with(json).get("nextTier.endThreshold");
System.out.println(endThreshold.doubleValue());
//149999.99
```